# what do you call someone who marries for citizenship?

Tags: terminology, epithet-requests

A gold digger is someone who marries for money. Is there a term for someone who marries for citizenship (and then divorces as soon as they get the citizenship)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's usually called a green card marriage.

Per wikipedia:

> Green card marriage is a neologism that refers to the marriage of convenience between a legal resident of a country and a person who would be ineligible for residency but for being married to a resident.

Comment: ...so the person would be called a green card wife?

Comment: Well since it is usually not a legal marriage, you wouldn't want to go around telling everyone that your wife or hubby was a *green card spouse.* When or why would you want to ever use the term? I guess you could tell trusted friends or family, but some secrets may be too big to tell anyone.